# Magento 2 Contact Form does not send email, but all transactional emails work

Tags: magento2, contact-us, contact-form, magento2.3.5-p1

In `Magento 2.3.5-p1` build we're having issues with the contact form sending emails.

On the client/user side, everything appears to work fine. The form submits without issue and then displays the success message.

However, we never actually receive the email in our inbox. All other emails seem to work, `account`, `orders/transactions`, etc.

Anybody have any ideas as to what would cause just the contact form to not send emails?

I'm assuming Magento uses the same method to send the contact form email as the other transactional emails?

I see nothing in the **logs** and as far as I can tell, the email appears to send, it just never ends up in our inbox (yes, we've checked the `Spam` folder as well).

Comment: Configuration->General->Contacts->Email Options->Send Emails To - I hope you have correct email id here. Just confirm that.

Comment: @KlausMikaelson yes, this value has been set, and I've tried multiple email addresses here, both within and outside of our company domain.